# How to approach mobile app content on Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We have a website that stores content for both desktop and mobile app. Mobile app retrieves content via Umbraco REST Api.

As content on each page could vary too much for desktop and app, we've come up with the only solution - keeping separate documents per each version. But this is very hard to maintain for content managers.

Any known solutions for the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a "Mobile content" tab on your regular doctype and put the mobile specific fields there? Then the urls would be the same but you could retrieve the mobile specific fields through JSON.

You could then even make a fallback so if the mobile field has no value, get the normal one instead.

Comment: Very good approach, especially when you need to have identical urls for both versions. But wouldn't it be too much in case of complex document type (let's say we have 10 tabs per version)?

Comment: Depends on how much content is different for mobile, I guess. If it isn't just a question of replacing one content tab (so you only have one extra "Mobile Content" tab) but also settings or stuff from other tabs, then it might result in tab overload.